# Trying to get arrayformula to work with SUM just like using IF

Tags: google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

I have a Google form that populates a sheet.  I can use arrayformula in 3 columns using a IF statement, example =ArrayFormula(if(H2:H="Yes",1,"")).  I use this in multiple columns.  I want the last column to SUM each row using arrayformula, so I don't have to copy formula all the way down the column, but it only adds all the rows and put answer in first cell instead of summing each row.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 0):

Use for instance if the different columns are within P and U

in row#1 (with header)

```
=ArrayFormula({"SOMMES";mmult(value(P2:U),transpose(column(P2:U)^0))})
```

or in row#2 (without header)

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult(value(P2:U),transpose(column(P2:U)^0)))
```

[MMULT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292)

Comment: I get this error: Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows (1).  My columns are P to U so I changed your formula to =ArrayFormula({"SOMMES";mmult(value(P2:U),transpose(column(P2:U)^0))})

Comment: sorry, this formula needs to be in row 1 and not in row 2 because the header is included

Comment: I recommand you to put usually your arrayformula in row#1 with the header as follows : `={"title";arrayformula(______)}`

Comment: @JamesLarsen : is it ok now ?